# How to hide a button in my ArcGIS AddIn

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in

I have developed an AddIn for ArcGIS 10.4 using Visual Studio 2015. My AddIn has several "buttons" defined in the config.esriaddinx XML file.

It is possible to completely **hide** a button when ArcMap starts? I know that I can override the button `OnUpdate()` event to *disable* the command, but I want to make it invisible to users.

My AddIn does have an Extension and I'm hoping I can put some code in the extension `OnStartUp()` event to either hide or remove a button.

Comment: Just thinking out aloud so do not know what the exact commands are (or if possible, but I would imagine it is). You don't hide buttons you would remove it from it's parent container, in this case the toolbar. Explore that.

Comment: Further to my comment have a look [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ICommandItem_Delete.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you know if this permanently removes them from the command bar? Or is it just for the current ArcMap session?

Comment: Good question,I would imagine it depends if the custom toolbar was stored in the MXD or normal template. If in the MXD and the MXD is saved then I would expect it to be permanently removed.